# Global maximum of Lagrangian vs global maximum of unconstrained function

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, lagrange-multiplier, quadratic-programming

Let's assume that $x$ is a matrix of parameters for the quadratic function $y=f(x)$ and $y$ is a scalar. Let's also assume that $x^{*}$ is such that  $y^{*}=f(x^{*})$ is a global minimum of $f(x)$ (as f is convex). Let's now consider the constrained minimization problem  $$min_{x} \quad f(x) \quad s.t. cond_1,..., cond_n$$ where we minimize the same function subject to a set of $n$ quadratic equality conditions, via the Lagrangian $L(x,\lambda_{1},...,\lambda_{n})=f(x)-\sum_{i}\lambda_{i}cond_{i}$

Let's assume this constrained minimization has multiple solutions (i.e. we find several stationary points). We want to test if one of the several solutions to the above mentioned constrained problem, denoted by $x^{sol}$ corresponds to a global minimum for the Lagrangian $L(x^{sol}, \lambda^{sol}_{1},..., \lambda^{sol}_{n})$ (where $\lambda^{sol}_{1},..., \lambda^{sol}_{n}$ are the lambdas corresponding to $x^{sol}$ found by solving the system of the partial derivatives with respect to $x$ and $\lambda_{1},..., \lambda_{n}$ equated to 0 as usual!).

My question is: in order to prove that $L(x_{sol}, \lambda_{sol})$ is a global minimum for L, is it **sufficient** to prove that $x^{sol}=x^{*}$, so that $f(x^{sol})=f(x^{*})$ is a global minimum for the unconstrained function?

In other words, given a global minimum $x^{*}$for $f(x)$, if $x^{*}$ satisfies the n conditions $cond_1,..., cond_n$, is it automatically a global minimum for the Lagrangian $L(x,\lambda_{1},...,\lambda_{n})$ without any need for further **formal** proofs?

Comment: @Rodrigo de Azevedo Edited with more paragraphs

Comment: @Rodrigo de Azevedo and everybody else.. More simply the question is: suppose I have a global minimum for the unconstrained function, and that minimum complies with the constraints (it is within the subdomain of y allowed by constraints).. is that automatically an optimum for the constrained problem (i.e. a global minimum of the corresponding Lagrangian) without any need to make any further proofs (like building the Lagrangian, solving, verifying the concavity of Lagrangian, its bordered Hessian, value of Lagrangian at all the stationary points to verify which is a global minimum..)?

Comment: If $f$ is quadratic, does it have a nice form? Why not write that nice form instead of using the symbol $f$?

Comment: @Rodrigo de Azevedo f is the multivariate Gaussian pdf as a function of the mean vector m=X*s where X is a matrix and s is a vector of appropriate size (same as y)

Comment: How is that $f$ quadratic? Its logarithm is quadratic, however.

Comment: @Rodrigo de Avezedo Yes sorry, I am minimizing the -log( multivariate_normal) with respect to X where X is in m=X*s .. I am very sorry for the bad spelling of the previous answer: my mind is boiled at this time of the evening :-( thanks a lot for your help in advance

Comment: Isn't that a quadratic form? Why not write it in matrix notation?

Comment: The constraints are equalities in a quadratic form as well of the kind $$X*D*X^{T} + C=0$$ where X is the matrix of unknowns, D and C are matrixes of appropriate size and $0$ is a matrix of $0$s. So I want to verify that a solution X^{*} to the constrained problem (I already know it is a solution because it works), which is also a global minimum for -log( pdf)) is a **global** minimum for the constrained problem: my reasoning was that if X^{*} minimizes the unconstrained function and complies with constraints then it must be a global minimum for the Lagrangian as well

Comment: Then this is not a QP, but a non-convex QCQP.

Comment: Why do you say it is non-convex? The function is minimized when y-m=0 right? So it has a global min

Comment: How can quadratic equality constraints be convex?

Comment: @Rodgrigo de Azevedo yes sure, now I get your point: of course the problem is a QCQP, although the function $f$ per se is a convex function with respect to X where X is in m=X*s.. yes.. that is why I do not want to solve the problem, but instead just prove that a solution $X_{*}$ that complies with constraints and corresponds to a global maximum for $f(X)$ is a solution to the more complex QCQP without the need to solve the QCQP and calculate $L(X_{*}, \lambda)$